# Changing a number of values in one column to the same number in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to make a new column with my data where all items in that column which have a result are labelled as 1 and then all pieces of data which are labelled as NA are named 0 (so creating two factors).

My column in R looks like this:

```
dates
NA
1970-01-01
NA
NA
1970-02-02
```

I created my new column using this `df$newcolumn <- df$dates`

I know that once I've made the new column that I can change the NA to 0 using this code:

```
df$newcolumn[is.na(df$newcolumn)] <- 0
```

But I can't work out at all how to do all my data which are currently displayed as dates. I tried changing the date to a numerical value (using `as.numeric(df$newcolumn)`) and then doing this:

```
df$newcolumn[df$newcolumn>0] <- 1
```

But when I do this it says the origin needs to be supplied.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `ifelse`:

```
within(df, newcolumn <- ifelse(is.na(dates), 0, 1))
```

Which is the same as:

```
df$newcolumn <- ifelse(is.na(df$dates), 0, 1)
```